# Invalid date constant: Trying to subset data into date range

Tags: date, sas, constants, range

I am a novice (and I mean NOVICE) SAS user.  I am trying to create a new table within a certain date range, but I am confused why it won't work for me.

I have a column doi (date of incident) in YYYY-MM-DD format.  I am trying to create a new table only within a date range, so I've put:

if "2020-01-01" <= doi =< "2020-03-29"

But the error message said "Invalid date/time/datetime contant". What can I do?

Thank you so much! SAS has been a struggle for me...

EDIT: Here was my original code:

```
data want; 
set sasdata.have
```

;
if "2020-01-01"d <= doi =< "2020-03-29"d;
run;

I just want to make a new table with all the variables within that date range. Thank you!!

Comment: Can you share more code, such as a minimally reproducible example.

Comment: Scroll to the bottom of this page to see how to form a date, time or datetime constant. (Worth bookmarking). https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lrcon/p0cq7f0icfjr8vn19vyunwmmsl7m.htm#:~:text=A%20SAS%20constant%20is%20a,Constants%20are%20also%20called%20literals%20.

Answer (score 1):

- `"2020-01-01"` is a string.
- `"01Jan2020"d` is a date constant.

See if that works for you :-)

Comment: Thank you! Is there anything  I need to do to "translate" 2020-01-01 to 01Jan2020 first? Here is the code I inputted:

data precovid; 
set opioid2020;
if "2020-01-01" <= doi =< "2020-03-29";
 run;

So is what you're saying is that all I need to do is replace the if line with if "01Jan2020"d <= doi <="29Mar2020"d;  ?

Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare numbers (dates are stored as number of days) to numbers instead of strings.  If you do include strings like in your example then SAS will try to convert them into numbers using the normal numeric informat which does not understand what to do with the hyphens.  So your test is just testing if DOI is missing.

```
447   data test;
448     format doi yymmdd10.;
449     if "2020-01-01" <= doi <= "2020-03-29" then put 'YES';
450   run;

NOTE: Character values have been converted to numeric values at the places given by: (Line):(Column).
      449:6    449:29
NOTE: Variable doi is uninitialized.
NOTE: Invalid numeric data, '2020-01-01' , at line 449 column 6.
NOTE: Invalid numeric data, '2020-03-29' , at line 449 column 29.
YES
doi=. _ERROR_=1 _N_=1
NOTE: The data set WORK.TEST has 1 observations and 1 variables.
```

If you want to enter a date constant then you need use a quoted string followed by the letter D.  The string inside the quotes needs to be something that the DATE informat can convert into a date value.

```
if "01-JAN-2020"d <= doi <= '29 MAR 2020'd then put 'YES';
if "01JAN2020"D <= doi <= '29MAR20'd then put 'YES';
```

You could also use the MDY() function to generate a date value.

```
if mdy(1,1,2020) <= doi <= mdy(3,29,2020) then put 'YES';
```

Or any other function that can generate a date value. Like the INPUT() function.

```
if input("2020-01-01",yymmdd10.) <= doi <= '29 MAR 2020'd then put 'YES';
```

It makes no difference to the comparison operators in the IF statement what date type format (YYMMDD, DATE, DDMMYY, MMDDYY, etc.) you have attached to the variable. Formats are just instructions for how to convert values to text, they do not change the values that are stored.

The key thing is that you need to compare the date values in your variables to other date values in your IF statement.  The examples above show a number of different ways of getting a date value into your program.

Comment: Thank you, Tom! I am still a little confused though. So, if my date format is currently in 2020-01-01 does this input("2020-01-01",yymmdd10.) tell SAS that is a date? And then it will already know 2020-03-29 is 29MAR2020? So I just add that line to my code? I am basically just trying to make a new table with all my variables within that data range, so my whole code is:

Comment: data precovid;
set opioid2020;
if input("2020-01-01",yymmdd10.) <= doi <= '29 MAR 2020'd then put 'YES';
run;

Is that all I need to do?

Comment: It does not matter what particular date type format you have attached to the variable to control how the values are displayed.  What matters is that you need to compare the date VALUES to other date VALUES.  I showed three ways to enter a constant date value.  Date constants (with multiple examples of types of ways you can specify dates with date) and two different function calls.

Comment: You probably do NOT want to run the PUT statement I had in my example, I just included it to help demonstrate the results of the comparison being made.  In your example you have a SUBSETTING IF statement that does not have the THEN and following statement.

Comment: Awesome, it worked!! Thank you very kindly!